# regex using dynamic input in Jmeter(regex extractor)

Tags: jmeter

I have a query regarding Jmeter regex extractor. I am trying to implement 1 scenario however not able to do same. Below are the details:

Requirement :

In Jmeter I have defined user defined variable : String VAR = KZ

now I am trying to use Regex extractor so that from the HTML response, regex will match VAR value in HTML(defined below) and will fetch span class name, as I need to set checkbox ON for KZ.

Requirement is to handle checkbox ON functionality through user defined variable, that  means I don't want to hardcode class name instead based on user defined variable(which will be td value i.e. in this example KZ) I have to fetch class name using Regex Extractor.  Could someone please help how to proceed?

Below is HTML Code:

```
<tr class="trClass">
<td style="width: 13.5%;">
<span class="checkbox"><input id="ctl00ctl94" type="checkbox" name="$ctl95$" 
 onclick="return validatecheck();" /></span>
</td>
<td style="width: 41.2%;"> KZ </td>
<td style="width: 0%; display: none;"> 5581357 </td>
<td style="width: 32%;"> 06/03/2018 2:22:38 PM </td>
</tr>
<tr class="trClass">
<td style="width: 13.5%;">
<span class="checkbox"><input id="ctl00ctl95" type="checkbox" name="$ctl95$" 
onclick="return validatecheck();" /></span>
</td>
<td style="width: 41.2%;"> TM </td>
<td style="width: 0%; display: none;"> 5581358 </td>
<td style="width: 32%;"> 06/03/2018 2:22:38 PM </td>
</tr>
<tr class="trClass">
<td style="width: 13.5%;">
<span class="checkbox"><input id="ctl00ctl96" type="checkbox" name="$ctl96$" 
onclick="return validatecheck();" /></span> </td>
<td style="width: 41.2%;">TR </td>
<td style="width: 0%; display: none;"> 5581359  </td>
<td style="width: 32%;"> 06/03/2018 2:22:38 PM  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) is not the best idea as:

- they are hard to develop and/or maintain
- they are very sensitive to markup change hence fragile, i.e. if order of attributes changes or something will go to a new line - it will simply ruin your regex

So I would recommend going for another post-processor which can work with DOM directly, for instance [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

The relevant XPath query which will fetch the classname of span which is above the `KZ` text would be something like:

```
//td[contains(text(),'KZ')]/preceding::*/span/@class
```

[image: JMeter View Results Tree]

Of course you can substitute `KZ` with the JMeter Variable reference, i.e.

```
//td[contains(text(),'${VAR}')]/preceding::*/span/@class
```

However you will not be able to test your queries using XPath Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, you will have to go for [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) instead to visualize the resulting variable.

Check out [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) and [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide to get familiarized with XPath language.

---

Also be aware that according to [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level**. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript** found in HTML pages.

So I don't believe fetching the span classname will solve your problem, most probably you will need to send underlying input name as a parameter so you should be looking for

```
//td[contains(text(),'KZ')]/preceding::*/span/input/@name
```

Comment: Hi Dmitri,
Above solution did work for me . Thank you